# Java lib that reads and writes xml or json w/ a simple switch

Tags: java, xml, json

Ideally writing should simply a matter of switching writers. One write would write json and another xml. The same would be true of the reverse, one factory takes an InputStream of json and another an InputStream of xml. In both cases the binding stuff would return an object stream given an InputStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) does this pretty darn well.

Normal instantiation (for XML):

```
new XStream();
```

Alternative instantiation (for JSON):

```
new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
/**************** or ****************/
new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
```

Comment: Nice - is XStream the equivalent of .NET WCF serialization in Java?

Comment: @Fakrudeen: I have no idea. I'm not a .NET or WCF programmer

Answer (score 1):

Also, while not a simple lib, JAX-RS implementations (like Jersey, RESTeasy) offer simple way to produce and consume both JSON and xml. They handle choice of backend library transparently based on media type being requested.

Build a facade is rather simple too; I would start by using [JAXB](http://jaxb.dev.java.net) for xml and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) for JSON; both can take InputStream or Reader, and output using OutputStream or Writer. And both do reasonably good job with data binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to code this yourself - it sounds like a good case for a [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and a [Factory Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)